# Extjs 3.4 multiples search in grid Costum logic

Tags: forms, search, extjs, grid, filtering

I'm looking something like this but for Extjs 3.4 Filtering with costum logic

```
var filters = [
     new Ext.util.Filter({
      filterFn: function(item){
         return item.get('GridFieldName') == searchValue && item.get('GridFieldName1') == searchValue;
      }
     })
];
store.filter(filters);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ext3.4 the config option is called `fn` instead of `filterFn` and you pass it as a config object and not as `Ext.util.Filter`, here is an example:

```
store.filter([
    {
        fn: function(item) {
            return item.get('GridFieldName') == searchValue && item.get('GridFieldName1') == searchValue;  
        }
    }
]);
```